# How to create an inaccessible window on Mac OS?

Tags: cocoa, macos, core-graphics, x11, macos-carbon

I mean a window which will not be accessible via Cocoa, Carbon or other CoreGraphics API for obtaining NSWindow *, WindowRef and others.

[Like X11 application on Mac does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110067/mac-os-x-window-server-vs-x11-the-insane-task).

Such a window that if you pass its window ID to [NSApp windowWithWindowID] or HIWindowFromCGWindowID() they both return NULL.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps, anybody is acquainted with libXplugin.dylib and Xplugin.h?
It uses undocumented CoreGraphics API CGSNewWindow(), etc in its function xp_create_window().

Comment: Because I need to get Graphics Port of X11 emulated window, but it does not respond on [NSApp windowWithWindowNumber: ] or HIWindowFromCGWindowID() from the very same process. And I'm curious how it creates its windows in such way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's CoreGraphics Private API. Its definition [is available](http://code.google.com/p/undocumented-goodness/source/browse/trunk/CoreGraphics/CGSPrivate.h) thanks to reverse engineering. If some window is created with such API it won't be accessible via [NSApp windowWithWindowNumber: (NSInteger)windowID] or HIWindowFromCGWindowID() functions.

Xquartz uses Xplugin library, which in turn uses CoreGraphics Private API.

Comment: shoumikhin, were you able to use it?, did it solve your problem? - I'm in the  same situation and wondering if this is THE path to the solution.